# Creating a user using node.js/postgres

Tags: node.js, postgresql

im getting an error when i try to create a user in the postgres db.
i added as much detail as i could below

error::

```
error: relation "users" does not exist
    at /Users/juan/Desktop/dev/code/dayt-back/node_modules/pg/lib/client.js:526:17
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5)
    at async create_user (/Users/juan/Desktop/dev/code/dayt-back/controllers/user/create_user.js:26:24) {
  length: 104,
  severity: 'ERROR',
  code: '42P01',
  detail: undefined,
  hint: undefined,
  position: '13',
  internalPosition: undefined,
  internalQuery: undefined,
  where: undefined,
  schema: undefined,
  table: undefined,
  column: undefined,
  dataType: undefined,
  constraint: undefined,
  file: 'parse_relation.c',
  line: '1395',
  routine: 'parserOpenTable'
}
```

controller that tries to create the user, this is where the error comes from::

```
// controllers/user/create_user.js


const pool = require('../../services/database');

const create_user = async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const { name, email, password, images, bio, gender, interested_sex } = req.body;

        // Remove the line extracting user ID from req.user

        const created_on = new Date().toISOString();
        const updated_on = created_on;

        console.log("name:", name);
        console.log("email:", email);
        console.log("password:", password);
        console.log("images:", images);
        console.log("bio:", bio);
        console.log("gender:", gender);
        console.log("interestedIn:", interested_sex);

        const client = await pool.connect();

        const imageUrls = ["one", "two"];
        const result = await client.query(
            'INSERT INTO "users" (name, email, password, images, bio, gender, interested_sex, created_on, updated_on) VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, $8, $9) RETURNING *',
            [name, email, password, imageUrls, bio, gender, interested_sex, created_on, updated_on]
        );

        res.json(result.rows[0]);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
        res.status(500).json({ error: 'Internal Server Error' });
    }
};

module.exports = {
    create_user,
};
```

here is how i created the table using the terminal, as you can when in print the tables it is present::

```
juan=# 
juan=# CREATE TABLE public.users (
juan(#     id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
juan(#     name VARCHAR(255),
juan(#     email VARCHAR(255),
juan(#     password VARCHAR(255),
juan(#     images JSONB,
juan(#     bio TEXT,
juan(#     gender VARCHAR(10),
juan(#     interested_sex VARCHAR(10),
juan(#     created_by INTEGER,
juan(#     updated_by INTEGER,
juan(#     created_on TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
juan(#     updated_on TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
juan(# );
CREATE TABLE
juan=# 
juan=# 
juan=# 
juan=# \dt                                                                             List of relations
 Schema | Name  | Type  | Owner 
--------+-------+-------+-------
 public | users | table | juan
(1 row)

juan=#
```

this is how i connect to the database::

```
// index.js
require('dotenv').config();

const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const { Pool } = require('pg');
const user_routes = require('./routes/user_routes');

const app = express();
const port = 3000;

// PostgreSQL configuration
const pool = new Pool({
    user: process.env.USER,
    host: process.env.HOST,
    database: process.env.DATABASE,
    password: process.env.PASSWORD,
    port: process.env.DB_PORT, // Use DB_PORT instead of PORT
});



// Start the server
app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Server is running on port ${port}`);
});



// services.database.js

const { Pool } = require('pg');

// PostgreSQL configuration
const pool = new Pool({
    user: process.env.USER,
    host: process.env.HOST,
    database: process.env.DATABASE,
    password: process.env.PASSWORD,
    port: process.env.PORT, // Use DB_PORT instead of PORT
});

module.exports = pool;
```

and finally, this is the database class::

```
// services.database.js

const { Pool } = require('pg');

// PostgreSQL configuration
const pool = new Pool({
    user: process.env.USER,
    host: process.env.HOST,
    database: process.env.DATABASE,
    password: process.env.PASSWORD,
    port: process.env.PORT, // Use DB_PORT instead of PORT
});

console.log(`Connected to database: ${process.env.DATABASE}`);  // Add this line

module.exports = pool;
```

i tried using chatgpt but it didnt help one bit.
i didnt find any useful stackoverflow posts.

i literally copied this video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O4bNwkC1ZxA&t=300s

if i change the line with the insert in the controller to::

```
      const result = await client.query(
            'INSERT INTO public.users (name, email, password, images, bio, gender, interested_sex, created_on, updated_on) VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, $8, $9) RETURNING *'
            [name, email, password, imageUrls, bio, gender, interested_sex, created_on, updated_on]
        );
```

i get a different error:

TypeError: Client was passed a null or undefined query
at Client.query (/Users/juan/Desktop/dev/code/dayt-back/node_modules/pg/lib/client.js:510:13)
at create_user (/Users/juan/Desktop/dev/code/dayt-back/controllers/user/create_user.js:26:37)
at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5)